# Отправка почты на несуществующий домен

Tags: email, smtp, exchange

Я через оутлук отправляю почту на +38044444444@**localhostname**. У меня на машине висит вин-сервис (самописный СМТП-сервер, кот. принимает сообщения), который слушает 25 порт на моей машине.

Через какое-то время, к моему СМТП подключается exchange сервер, который передает ему мое сообщение.

**Вопрос:**
Правильная ли у меня логика: 
после того как я отправил почту на +38044444444@**localhostname**, почтовый сервер принял его, понял что не может отправить почту на этот домен, и проэтмоу он начал искать СМТП-сервер  в домене **localhostname**, нашел его - (мой самописный вин-сервис) и передал ему сообщения.

**Все верно? Так оно работает? (1)**

**Есть еще один вопрос (2):**

Если отправить несколько подобных писем (напр., меня только номер телефона в получателе), то я получаю только 1 первое сообщение, а  остальные не приходят. приходится перезапускать СМТП сервис, чтобы он смог принимать сообщения снова.
В чем может быть причина? Я не пойму где причина - в моем СМТП или в **exchange**.

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Я бы выразился по другому "exchange понял, что localhostname - это не тот домен для которого ему сказали принимать почту локально (в свои ящики), поэтому он поступил с ней, как с любой другой исходящей почтой, нашел MX запись для домена получателя и отправил на указанный там SMTP"

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за подсказку. А по второму вопросу сможете подсказать?

Comment: И по хорошему exchange должно быть плевать сколько писем вы отправляете. Каждое письмо он должен передать. В его логах (у него же есть логи ?) должно быть видно что происходит с письмами, передал ли он ихследующему smtp и если нет - то почему

Comment: Из всех отправленных сообщений я получаю только одно - 1ое.

Comment: Так что я почти уверен, что проблема в вашем сервисе. exchange может например не разрывать соединение, а слать следующее письмо в том же коннекте. ваш сервис продолжает ждать следующих писем на том же соединении ? А если он ждет на соединении, он одновременно готов принимать новые соединения и делать для них accept

Comment: В моем сервисе, судя по логам, диалог обрывается на команде "bdat" - т.е .я получил от exchange  текст письма, и  все. больше никаких команд от него не поступало.

Comment: Ну команд в этом соединении может и не поступает. А другие соединения exchange пытается устанавливать ? Я к тому, что может вы ждете на соединении данных и из за этого не можете принять новое соединение. Вы используете неблокирующий ввод/вывод в сокетах и можете поддерживать несколько сессий одновременно ? Еще желательно по таймаутам закрывать соединения если они без дела висят долго

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду думать. Я использую TcpListener для прослушки 25 порта иcleintSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket() дял приема информации

Comment: Я не в курсе чем под виной сейчас принято с сокетами работать и неблокирующее ли оно. Тупо телнетом на свой 25 порт попробуйте соединится, когда сервис только запущен и когда его заклинило.